# Can columns in google chart be assigned multiple roles?

Tags: google-visualization, roles

Currently I have columns in google chart with one role already assigned as "tooltip" but I also need to assign "certainty" roles to the columns. Is that possible?

Comment: it is possible, just add the columns after the other(s).

Comment: If you want one column to serve multiple roles, that is not possible directly, but you can easily copy the column using a DataView.

Comment: Okay, I get how dataview can be used to set column role but I can't figure out how to insert values for the role for each respective row with the already existing roles? Thanks so much!